# How to use MapRoute, using ActionLink()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, target

I have this route values inside `Global.asax`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Edit", // Route name
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Edit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and I use this ActionLink method to call the Edit route

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Topic", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
```

Now the result of the link generated is like this...

```
http://localhost:777/Admin/Topic?Length=4
```

How to use the route and target properly using the ActionLink method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct overload of `ActionLink` to get the intended result

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Topic", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }, null)
```

The overload is `ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)`

Adding the `null` as null HTML attributes is necessary when you supply parameters to the action. Or if you actually needed to apply HTML Attributes to the link, you would use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Topic", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "MyCustomCssClassName" } )
```

Comment: Html.RouteLink() is much better.